# Pass parameter using AJAX to a switch instructions block in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a dropdown list as follow:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="rubChoice">
    <li><a href="#ticker" id="act1" data-item="Sport">Sport</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ticker" id="act2" data-item="Politique">Politique</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ticker" id="act3" data-item="International">International</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ticker" id="act4" data-item="Divers">Divers</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm using AJAX and jQuery to send `data-item` values to a PHP code. The AJAX code part:

```
$('#rubChoice').on("click", "a", function(e) {
    var option = e.target.getAttribute('data-item');
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(option);
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/rss/core/inc/rssnews.inc.php',
          data: { Option : option },
          success: function(data)
            {
               alert("success!");
            }
           });
                });
```

At the php side (`rssnews.inc.php`), the script is like that:

```
function selectURL() {
    if(isset($_POST['Option']))
    {
        $uid = $_POST['Option'];

        // Do whatever you want with the $uid
        print_r($uid);
    }
    return $uid;
}
```

I want to use the recovered values in a switch case in other function called `getFeed()` like that:

```
function getFeed () {
    switch ($uid) {
            case "Sport":
                $url = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/GalerieArtciles';
                break;
            case "International":
                $url = 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int#';
                break;
            case "Politique":
                $url = 'http://www.elkhabar.com/feeds/';
                break;
            default: $url = 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int#';
    }
    // use $url in other operations
}
```

But I still uncapable getting result. So, how can I perform this action ?

Comment: how you call getFeed from selectURL ?

Comment: @bxN5 I don't perform an call

Comment: @bxN5 It seem that the `$uid` variable didn't get the `data-item` attribute, when I see the Network on Google Chrome using F12. I dn't get any display of the `$uid` value